# How to merge specific values in pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this problem would be somewhere in `SO` but I can't find it anywhere. How can you `merge` specific values in a `pandas column`? For the `df` below I only want to `merge` values in `Col A,B` when they are `Foo,Bar` and leave everything else.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['Foo','No'],
    'B' : ['Bar','Bar'],
   })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I do this:

```
df["A"] = df["A"].map(str) + df["B"] 

        A    B
0  FooBar  Bar
1   NoBar  Bar
```

Where as I'm hoping to output:

```
        A    B
0  FooBar     
1      No  Bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
idx=(df.A == 'Foo' )& (df.B == 'Bar')
df.loc[idx, 'A']  = df.loc[idx, 'A'] + df.loc[idx, 'B']
df.loc[idx, 'B'] = ''

    A       B
0   FooBar  
1   No      Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mask = (df[['A', 'B']].values == ['Foo','Bar']).all(axis=1)

df['A'] = np.where(mask, df["A"] + df["B"], df['A'])
df['B'] = np.where(mask, '', df["B"])
print (df)

        A    B
0  FooBar     
1      No  Bar
```